# Dropdown compatibility issues with jquery 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a compatibility issues with jquery 1.7.1

```
// menu-nav
$('#nav-menu ul ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li:first').addClass('first');
    $(this).children('li:last').addClass('last');
});
$('#nav-menu ul li.expanded').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('a').addClass('hover');
        $('ul:first',this).stop().css({height: 'auto', overflow:'', paddingTop: '2px'}).slideDown(250);
    },
    function(){
        $('ul:first',this).stop().slideUp(150, function() 
    {$(this).parent('li').children('a').removeClass('hover');}).css({height:'auto'});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEk6X/)

I'm not sure what I should do to get this working again.

Comment: And the concrete problem is?

Comment: Your fiddle had a syntax error, which I have corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEk6X/1/ -- is there still a problem?

Comment: Thank you @ExplosionPills , the problem is that i have currently jquery 1.7.1 but my dropdown menu stopped working.

Comment: 1.7.2 fixes a bunch of issues in 1.7.1. There are very limited circumstances under which you might still want to use 1.7.1.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description.